# Error with VB ParseFileText method

Tags: vb.net, indexoutofrangeexception

When I run this I made a dummy "Button1" to test populate the fields they will successfully fill out the texts boxes. How ever I will have it parse that file every minute, and when I do it again I get the error shown below. By adding the routine "DisplayForm_Load" to the button1_click even it would work fine.

My question is I'm pretty sure I shouldn't have to redefine this every time? I think I'm not setting the index back to 0 or something along those lines. From what I've been able to understand from MS website is its like its indexing things in the array that don't exist.

Error received:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in WindowsApplication4.exe

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO
```

Public Class Form1

```
Private Directory As String ' Used to hold the folder directory to push/pull data from.
Private FileParser As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser

Private Sub PushButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles PushButton.Click
    ' Sends information to txt file. 
    ' This bit works fine, just writes code to txt file that can be parsed below.
End Sub

Sub DefineTextFieldParse_Load() Handles MyBase.Load
    ' Instantiate teh TextFieldParser and the set the delimiter
    Dim FileName As String = "C:\Users\Caleb\Documents\TestDoc.txt"

    Try
        FileParser = New FileIO.TextFieldParser(FileName)   '' Selects File to Parse
        FileParser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited
        FileParser.SetDelimiters(",")
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Errors
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to read the file" & "," & FileName)
    End Try
End Sub

Sub UpdateCheck()
    ' Checks share txt file for update. 
    Dim FileName As String = "C:\Users\<Me>\Documents\TestDoc.txt"
    Dim FieldString() As String

    'Read the file
    If Not FileParser.EndOfData Then
        FieldString = FileParser.ReadFields()
        ' 1st Field
        NIS1TextBox.Text = FieldString(0)
        ' 2nd Field
        NIS2TextBox.Text = FieldString(1)
    ' You get the idea...All Testboxes identified above in the write section
    ' Repeats 12 more times...
        EODTextBox.Text = FieldString(14)
        InfoRichTextBox.Text = FieldString.LastOrDefault()
    End If

End Sub

Sub PushUpdate()

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'DefineTextFieldParse_Load()_Load() ' When Enabled code works fine when commented out generates alert.
    UpdateCheck()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: On which line does the exception get thrown? What index is being used on that line? What is the valid range for that index?

Comment: I would suggest that you don't have a single `TextFieldParser` object.  You should create one when and where you need one and destroy it immediately afterwards.  You should create it with a `Using` statement and then it will be implicitly destroyed at the end of the block. When you do that, there's no possibility of something being held over from the last use.

Answer (score 0):

mchihinney - I did review https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hks5e2k6.aspx

However what I found was the issue was with the formatting of the text file. The problem I found was with the text file there was a second line which was blank, so when it tried to parse nothing it through the error. Deleting the second line from the .txt file and worked as expected.